# hf-tikz in the background

Tags: hf-tikz

I use `hf-tikz` quite often in my beamer presentations.
One thing that I find quite annoying each time that I use it is that, if the rectangle providing the highlighting happens to be over some text preceding the one enclosed by the `\tizmarkin` and `\tikzmarkend` commands, such text is hidden.

See, for instance, this MWE

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[beamer]{hf-tikz}    
\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \begin{align*}
            \mathbf{\hat{f}}(\tikzmarkin<2>[above left offset={-1.1,0.35},below right offset={1.0,-1.35}]{myhl}t+R\tikzmarkend{myhl}) &=  a + b + c
        \end{align*}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

yielding this (the misalignment is due to bad screenshots)

[image]

[image]

Is there a way to avoid this? Or (as I fear) is it part of the way `hf-tikz` works and cannot, thus, be somehow bypassed?

Comment: it would be easier to see two images than an animated one (perhaps it's just me but I find the cycle rate of this particularly painful)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle fair enough. I edited the post

Comment: @AndreyTyukin What are you hoping to find with this bounty? Nowadays, `hf-tikz` is not my first choice to highlight parts of a equation. The `tikzmark` package/library is very advanced and can deal with this much better. What are you trying to highlight actually? There's probably no need to manually adjust the offsets anymore.

Comment: Actually, I had completely forgotten about this and can't even recall that I set a bounty on this question. As a matter of fact, after all these years the question is completely irrelevant to me (I'm not even using LaTeX anymore :D :D). Regardless. good luck to whoever will get the bounty.

Edit: Wait, I just realised that it seems like it wasn't me starting the bounty. OK, I was very confused with all these answers popping up years later, and didn't realised that bounties can't be active for so long :|

Comment: @gbernardi Sorry for the confusion. I just was googling around a few days ago, ran into this question. It seemed to describe exactly the problem that I was facing, and it already included example code and illustrations. Since there were no answers, but I wanted to see how to make it work, I started a bounty. Obligatory XKCD precisely describing the situation: [Wisdom of the Ancients](https://xkcd.com/979). So, yeah, uhm... Even though it comes 7 years too late: thanks for the effort on illustrations.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin: No problem at all. I'm actually happy to see that something obscure I wrote 8 years ago (and that probably gave me enough a headache to motivate me to write a stackoverflow question) can be helpful for someone else. Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

The `hf-tikz` is almost ten years old and doesn't offer much what you couldn't just do with `tikzmark` directly which is basically what I've done here but with the original interface of `hf-tikz`.

This is: mark the begin and the end of the to highlighted part but `\tikzmarkdraw` it as early as possible so that it gets drawn *before* `\mathbf{\hat{f}}` gets put onto the page but it needs to be on the same page.
With `beamer` this is very easy because you know where the pagebreaks are.

You could just put all `\tikzmarkdraw`s at the start of the frame.

### Code

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[beamer]{hf-tikz}
\NewDocumentCommand{\tikzmarkbegin}{m}{\tikzmarkend{begin-#1}}
\NewDocumentCommand{\tikzmarkdraw}{D<>{.-} O{} m}{%
  \only<#1>{%
    \tikz[remember picture,overlay]\draw[hf/rect,#2]
        ([shift={(\aboveleftoff)}]pic cs:begin-#3) rectangle
%        node [anchor=base] (node-#3) {}
        ([shift={(\belowrightoff)}]pic cs:#3);%
  }%
}
\tikzset{hf/rect/.style={line width=+1pt, fill=\fcol, draw=\bcol, rounded corners}}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{align*}
\tikzmarkdraw<2>[above left offset={-1.1,0.35},below right offset={1.0,-1.35}]{myhl}
\mathbf{\hat{f}}(\tikzmarkbegin{myhl} t + R\tikzmarkend{myhl}) &=  a + b + c
\end{align*}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It is not necessary to move the hf-tikz annotation to the background. You can change the `blend mode` instead:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[beamer]{hf-tikz}    
\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \begin{align*}
            \mathbf{\hat{f}}(\tikzmarkin<2>[above left offset={-1.1,0.35},below right offset={1.0,-1.35},blend mode=multiply]{myhl}t+R\tikzmarkend{myhl}) &=  a + b + c
        \end{align*}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That's an interesting approach, thank you! Do I understand correctly that it assumes black text on a white background? Could it lead to unexpected results if the background is not just white, e.g. in presentations where there is some background image?

Comment: @AndreyTyukin As long as the text/background colour is sufficiently different from the hf-tikz colour, it should nevertheless produce a readable result. For extremely different colour themes, e.g. white text on dark background, maybe one can experiment with some of the other available blend modes.

Answer (score 2):

As you are showing the box only on the second overlay, you could use the `tikzmark` library and draw the background before the equation:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamertemplate{background canvas}{\includegraphics[scale=2]{example-image-duck}}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,fit}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
  \node<2> [draw=pink!50!violet,thick,fill=orange!30!white, rounded corners, inner xsep=7pt, fit=(myhl)] {};
  \end{tikzpicture}
    \begin{align*}
        \mathbf{\hat{f}}(\tikzmarknode{myhl}{t+R}) &=  a + b + c
    \end{align*}
    \pause
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

If you would like to show it on all overlays, you could add it to the background layer:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamertemplate{background canvas}{\includegraphics[scale=2]{example-image-duck}}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,fit}
\begin{document}

{
\addtobeamertemplate{background canvas}{}{  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
  \node [draw=pink!50!violet,thick,fill=orange!30!white, rounded corners, inner xsep=7pt, fit=(myhl)] {};
  \end{tikzpicture}
}
\begin{frame}
    \begin{align*}
        \mathbf{\hat{f}}(\tikzmarknode{myhl}{t+R}) &=  a + b + c
    \end{align*}
\end{frame}
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Do you know whether the `\tikzmarknode` could interfere with the `&`-markers of `align`-environment if one decides to highlight parts separated by the `&`?

Comment: @AndreyTyukin I wouldn't place the alignment markers in the node. If you want to draw across multiple "cells" of the align, use normal `\tikzmark`s and then fit the shape around all the marks

Comment: ... or use a nicematrix instead

Comment: @AndreyTyukin Here an example how to fit shapes around multiple tikzmarks https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/502486/36296