# Coloring the backgrounds of portions of a matrix

Tags: matrices

I've been looking around for some time and I seem to be having a large bit of trouble coloring the following matrix:

```
\begin{pmatrix}  3 & -1 & -1 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        -1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        -1 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        -1 & 0 & 0 & 2 & -1 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 3 & -1 & -1 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & -1 & 3 & -1 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & -1 & 2 \end{pmatrix}
```

As below:

[image]

Would anyone know where I would start to do this? Everything I've seem to come across seems to have been specially written for a particular matrix and I've been having trouble adapting the codes.

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/69713/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Apart from the [possibilities listed in Zarko's comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/69713/), you can use `tikzmark`, which gives you an arguably finer automatic control. In your use-case, however, the finer control is not needed but it might be if you have more fancy entries in the matrix like stuff with exponents.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,fit}
\begin{document}
\AddToShipoutPictureBG{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
 \node[fill=blue!40,rounded corners,fit=(m1)(m3)]{};
 \node[fill=red!40,rounded corners,fit=(m2)(m4)]{};
 \node[fill=purple!60,inner xsep=1.6ex,rounded corners,fit=(m2)(m3)]{};
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\[\begin{pmatrix}  
    \tikzmarknode{m1}{3} & -1 & -1 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        -1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        -1 & 0 & \tikzmarknode{m2}{2} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        -1 & 0 & 0 & \tikzmarknode{m3}{2} & -1 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 3 & -1 & -1 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & -1 & 3 & -1 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & -1 & \tikzmarknode{m4}{2}
\end{pmatrix}\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Appendix (by BlackMild): This is a minor change from mamot's code. I remove the third node, and use `opacity=.3` and `inner sep=4pt` for the first and the second `node`s, so their colors are self-mixing.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,fit}
\begin{document}
\AddToShipoutPictureBG{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture,opacity=.3,inner sep=4pt]
\node[fill=blue,fit=(m1)(m3)]{};
\node[fill=red,fit=(m2)(m4)]{};
\end{tikzpicture}
}
    \[\begin{pmatrix}  
        \tikzmarknode{m1}{3} & -1 & -1 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        -1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        -1 & 0 & \tikzmarknode{m2}{2} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        -1 & 0 & 0 & \tikzmarknode{m3}{2} & -1 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 3 & -1 & -1 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & -1 & 3 & -1 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & -1 & \tikzmarknode{m4}{2}
    \end{pmatrix}\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why a community post?

Comment: @manooooh I want to leave and additional reputation points delay it. Do you have a suggestions for posts that deserve a bounty?

Comment: ohh *fast* marmot came out!! I don't understand your question.

Comment: @manooooh I am awarding points to good answers. If you know a good and original answers, I could put them on my list. (And once I am low enough in points, I will leave this site for good.)

Answer (score 3):

You can easily do that with `{pNiceMatrix}` of `nicematrix`.

In that environment, you have a built-in command `\Block` and you can fill a block with the color you want.

In order to show that this works even in presence of a background, I have put the environment `{pNiceMatrix}` in a `{tcolorbox}` (user121799's answer does not work with a background).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}
\[\begin{pNiceMatrix}[margin]  
\Block[fill=blue!40,rounded-corners]{4-4}{}
3  & -1 & -1 & -1 & 0  & 0  & 0  \\
-1 & 1  & 0  & 0  & 0  & 0  & 0  \\
-1 & 0  & \Block[fill=red!40,rounded-corners]{*-*}{}
          2  & 0  & 0  & 0  & 0  \\
-1 & 0  & 0  & 2  & -1 & 0  & 0  \\
0  & 0  & -1 & 0  & 3  & -1 & -1 \\
0  & 0  & 0  & -1 & -1 & 3  & -1 \\
0  & 0  & 0  & 0  & -1 & -1 & 2 
\end{pNiceMatrix}\]
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes).

[image: Output of the first code]

You can use the key `opacity` (requires v. 6.22 of `nicematrix`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}
\[\begin{pNiceMatrix}[margin]  
\Block[fill=blue!40,rounded-corners]{4-4}{}
3  & -1 & -1 & -1 & 0  & 0  & 0  \\
-1 & 1  & 0  & 0  & 0  & 0  & 0  \\
-1 & 0  & \Block[fill=red!80,opacity=0.5,rounded-corners]{*-*}{}
          2  & 0  & 0  & 0  & 0  \\
-1 & 0  & 0  & 2  & -1 & 0  & 0  \\
0  & 0  & -1 & 0  & 3  & -1 & -1 \\
0  & 0  & 0  & -1 & -1 & 3  & -1 \\
0  & 0  & 0  & 0  & -1 & -1 & 2 
\end{pNiceMatrix}\]
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the second code]

If you want the red block behind the blue one, this technic won't work. In that case, it's possible to use the `\CodeBefore` provided by `{pNiceMatrix}` in order to draw the colored rectangles with Tikz *before* the construction of the array (using Tikz nodes created by `nicematrix` in the matrix).

Once again, this works even with a background.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}
\[\begin{pNiceMatrix}[margin]  
\CodeBefore
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \fill [red!40,rounded corners] (3-|3) rectangle (8-|8) ;
  \fill [blue!40,rounded corners] (1-|1) rectangle (5-|5) ;
  \end{tikzpicture}
\Body
3  & -1 & -1 & -1 & 0  & 0  & 0  \\
-1 & 1  & 0  & 0  & 0  & 0  & 0  \\
-1 & 0  & 2  & 0  & 0  & 0  & 0  \\
-1 & 0  & 0  & 2  & -1 & 0  & 0  \\
0  & 0  & -1 & 0  & 3  & -1 & -1 \\
0  & 0  & 0  & -1 & -1 & 3  & -1 \\
0  & 0  & 0  & 0  & -1 & -1 & 2 
\end{pNiceMatrix}\]
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the third code]